# Get suppress condition and format conditions from crystal report using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using [CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225594%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the properties of FormulaField,FieldObject etc. But how to get **suppress conditions** of FieldObject and also conditions given for font,font style etc.

I downloaded code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/)  and modified it to include properties which i needed.But i didnt get documentation related to getting suppress and any conditions given in format field etc

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DataConditionFormulaClass Member of CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel
```

[Documentation](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RAS_SDK/rassdk_net_doc/doc/rassdk_net_doc/html/CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel~CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.DataConditionFormulaClass_members.html)